# Processing CSV File

Tags: c#, file, csv

I am using  `Sebastien Lorion`[Reference](http://beta.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx?msg=3429434) CSV reader to process my CSV file in C# 3.0.

Say example

```
id|name|dob (Header)
1|sss|19700101 (data)
2|xx|19700201  (data)
```

My Business Object is

```
class Employee
{
   public string ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Dob {get;set;}
}
```

I read the CSV stream and stored it in `List<string[]>`

```
List<string[]> col = new List<string[]>();

using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader
               (new StreamReader("D:\\sample.txt"), true, '|'))
{
    col = csv.ToList();
}
```

How to iterate over the list to  get each Employee like

```
     foreach (var q in col)
    {
        foreach (var r in q)
        {
            Employee emp=new Employee();
            emp.ID =r[0];
            emp.Name=r[1];
            emp.Dob=r[2];
        }
    }
```

If i call `r[0],r[1],r[2]` i am getting "`index out of range exception`".How the process the list to avoid the error?

### Edit

Sorry I got the result.
When i process

```
 foreach (var q in col)
{

        Employee emp=new Employee();
        emp.ID =q[0];
        emp.Name=q[1];
        emp.Dob=q[2];

}
```

things work fine.

Comment: Are you getting the error on some lines or all lines?

Comment: After ignoring the header ,when i process the rest of the lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to read such a reader would be, for example:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
using (IDataReader csv = new CsvReader
             (new StreamReader("D:\\sample.txt"), true, '|'))
{
    while(csv.Read()) {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.ID = r.GetString(0); // or int.Parse(...) if it is an int
        emp.Name = r.GetString(1);
        emp.Dob = r.GetString(2); // or DateTime.Parse(...) if it is a DateTime
        employees.Add(emp);
    }
}
```

You could also use an iterator block, and you *might* be able to use `GetDateTime` / `GetInt32`, but I couldn't say for sure so I've just used `GetString` in the above.

Comment: Wow! When Jon Skeet and Marc Gravell is there you can clarify anything